# New Tires, car shaking/bouncing at high speeds

Tags: tires, wheels, steering, vibration

I just had some Uniroyal Tiger Paws put on my 2010 Escape. When I first left the shop, they felt great until I hit about 60ish mph. Then I got the bouncing, steering wheel vibration like they hadn't balanced them correctly. So I took it back and they re-balanced. They said two were out .25 and one was out .5. Not really enough to cause that though the bouncing/vibration took a bit longer to occur, more like 65. But oh my gosh, get over 80 and forget about it. It feels unsafe. This is not fixed. Could an out of round tire cause this and should I bring it back to the same tire place (walmart) or at this point should I find a mechanic to look at it? The car has 139k miles on it. An alignment maybe? Though the car does not pull at all to either side. Thank you

Comment: You definitely need shocks. It's also possible you have a large imbalance in brake rotors or prop shafts.  There are repair shops that can test that. They jack up car on a jack with force sensor, then spin the tire externally and measure the system out of balance condition.

Comment: The big question is; did you have this problem BEFORE you bought the new tires?

Comment: I did not have this problem before the new tires. I had old mismatched tires before. As a note, I really paid attention this morning and the bouncing is worse up or down hills. Just like an unbalanced or out of round tire. Is there anything else that could cause that?

Comment: There are too many things it could be for us to know for sure. I am suspicious of the new tires or mounting. Improper mounting of tire to the rim, the rim to the car and bad tires can cause all types of issues. Wal-Mart has brand name tires made to their own specifications and as cheaply as possible. Since you have taken it back to Wal-Mart and they think nothing is wrong, I would take it to another reputable tire shop, explain what it going on and ask them to evaluate it. You may have to pay them a fee, but they can find the issue.

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I intend to do this afternoon. I was hoping by getting a brand name tire that I would avoid this instead of those terrible Viva's made just for Walmart.

Answer (score 2):

Yes out of round tyres can cause this.. I've experienced it the odd time, but normally only with cheaper tyres. I had a couple of tyres a few years ago that made my whole car bounce slightly due to their sort of elliptical shape.

First though.. have the tyre place check that your new tyres are seated on the rims properly, as this can cause the problem your describing if they're not.

Answer (score 1):

An alignment is certainly in order, considering they have been balanced (twice!)

Did you have the same issue with your old tyres?

Comment: I didn't and they were mismatched, very low on tread tires. This is why I'm leaning towards the tires.

Answer (score 1):

If the tires are brand new they shouldn't be out of round unless through manufacturer defect or improper storage. If I understand what they said was that your tires were out a 1/4 to 1/2 ounce. Even the small amount of weight when accelerated to highway speeds can generate significant imbalance. If that is the condition on all 4 tires then the resulting constant shifting of forces would make driving difficult. Have them re-balanced at another tire place. Other things to possibly check out are possible suspension issues such as shocks, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Ask for a 2 plane balance. That is the best way to have the weight split so the 1/4 oz and 1/4 oz making 1/2 oz is not putting only on the inside. Example. The machine will show where the weight is needed. Putting all the weight on the inside so you don't see the lead....appearance (show) .balancing the inside/and /outside will help high speed rotation...75 mph++  . Today's car need proper care and it's over looked when it comes to air pressure and suspension. Roads are (tricky) even if you know where that pothole you pass every day becomes a (s***) I can't believe I hit it.. rotate /inflate. They (tires) aren't cheap.

Comment: Have someone follow behind you and watch for wheel hop.(bouncing tire) . A bad shock/strut front or back will be seen easier by another driver looking for the problem. A tire that has a broken band (steel cord) will kind of make an  egg shape (bulge) and while spinning will wobble especially at low speed when first pulling away from a dead stop. At higher speed it might not feel like a problem but it really is. The tire will heat up and get worse even blow out is possible and that's not good. I had a tire go flat and a plug put in and 1 month later the steel cord broke and the tire was bad.

Answer (score 1):

If your car doesn't have anti lock brakes...Front or rear as my 2005 Dodge neon (non antilock rear) front only. Tires got a flat spot after a hard brake and rear tires skid( not long )but being new tires a noise developed with a (tap...tap..tap..)then with more miles it became a (thump.thump.thump ) sound. You can't fix it. Had to buy 2 new tires even though only 5000 miles on them. Not a defect,  Sucks not knowing this can happen. Summer time is the worse .